# Tab Slider Animation for Tab Items in Flex in Pure CSS

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

I have been trying to create my own React `Tabs` component with sliding animation, similar to [mui](https://mui.com/components/tabs/) or [ant design](https://ant.design/components/tabs/).

I can do it if it include js, however the catch here is that I can't use css in js or inline css. Therefore it's purely scss / css in Nextjs project. Another catch is that the tab is responsive (no fix width), so the container is `flex` and it can contain multiple tab items which is `flexItems` (may contain different width). Therefore I can't find a way to get the width of the item in pure css.

Is it possible to create animation like that without any JS?

Comment: You could make your tabs radio buttons and style them with a look and feel of a tab button. Then use the :checked pseudo class with transform translateX on a pseudo element :after/:before to control the slider. Just search sliding menu tabs with radio buttons and I sure you'll get a hit or two that will assist you on getting started.

Comment: I did search, I got what you meant, however the `translateX` doesn't know where to go because `Tabs` can contain multiple items as a flexItems. It doesn't have a fix amount of item, it is a component. @dalelandry

Answer (score 0):

Will try to help you

You need to create separate functional component `Tabs` as I understood.

You can define proper `css` in each component.

**1. Option with defining styles as components**

RAW example:

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Title = styled.h1`
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: palevioletred;
`;

// Create a Wrapper component that'll render a <section> tag with some styles
const Wrapper = styled.section`
  padding: 4em;
  background: papayawhip;
`;

export default function Example(){

  return(
    <div>
      <Wrapper>
      <Title>
        Hello World!
      </Title>
    </Wrapper>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Please check this docs, how to use properly [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#installation)

**2. Option 2: basic CSS styling**

You create your `global.css` and define all your styles css [there](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/css-global).

**3. You find on web your `Tab slider` examples.** (for example check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172546/before-and-after-slider-using-css-unable-to-re-size-image-lesser-than-the-ini))

For your thinking about `pure css project` - NextJS anyway transforms all your pages
in `.js` or `.tsx`, so you can't really write in pure `html` `css` with no transformation in `.js`

I don't know why you try to avoid `.js` in `js/tsx` framework. With pure css you will have a lot of problems, because each browser has own :white/black" lists for each component and `css` property, here is [table](https://caniuse.com/?search=flex)